# rails seed DB file

Tags: ruby, seed

Guys now i want to add just data in my users Table just for test with it
so I'm trying from use this code

```
users.create(:name => "admin",:user => "admin",:pass=> "123")
```

in the seed file  then when it trying to run `rake db:seed`

it always gave me error

my table structure  was

```
create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :user
      t.string :pass

      t.timestamps
```

so i want to know what is the best way to add data to the DB using the seed file

Comment: undefined local variable or method 'users' for main : object

Comment: chnage `users` to `User`

Answer (score 3):

change

```
users.create(:name => "admin",:user => "admin",:pass=> "123")
```

to

```
User.create(:name => "admin",:user => "admin",:pass=> "123")
```

Model names in rails are singular, while the table name is plural

Comment: when i used the command User.create(:name => "admin",:user => "admin",:pass=> "123") it gives me the same error but then i used the command Users.create(:name => "admin",:user => "admin",:pass=> "123") it not gave me any error but now when i tried to use the command Rails c  then Users.All to show the data from the command screen  it gave me the error unintialized constant Ur

Comment: @Astm means you defined your model as `Users` instead of `User` which is a bad practice in rails and you might end up with issues

Comment: @Astm you need to call it `User` and not `Users` to avoid unexpected behavior(s), and do accept the answer if it works for you

Comment: how i can change the model name ??  my model now created with the name Users

Comment: change the file name `app/models/users.rb` to `app/models/user.rb` and change `class Users < ActiveRecord::Base` to `class User < ActiveRecord::Base`

Answer (score 0):

Its work well now by Using the command

```
Users.create(:name =>"admin",:user =>"admin",:pass=>"123")
```

then run the command `rake db:seed` on the screen command then restart the server

the I can see the data from the screen command by typing the command

```
rails c
Users.all
```

my error was i typed

```
users.create(:name =>"admin",:user =>"admin",:pass=>"123")
```

not

```
Users.create(:name =>"admin",:user =>"admin",:pass=>"123")
```

the model name must be capital 
"Users" not "users"

thanks guys for tying to help me  :)